# Transit in Australia

Tags: australia, transit

I am traveling from Singapore to New Zealand.
My trip consists of a stop in Australia, Brisbane.
Where I have to get my luggage and re-check in at the counters in Brisbane.

I'm a Singaporean.
Will I need to apply for a transit Visa?

Answer (score 4):

According to the Department of Immigration and Citizenship, [citizens from Singapore are not required a visa if on transit](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/transit/visa-options.htm):

> Non-Australian citizens from certain countries are eligible to transit through Australia without a visa.
>   The following categories of travellers are covered under this arrangement:
>
> Citizens of the these countries: Andorra, Argentina, Austria, Belgium,
>   Brunei, Canada, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Federated
>   States of Micronesia, Fiji, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary,
>   Iceland, Indonesia, Ireland, Italy, Japan, Kiribati, Latvia,
>   Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malaysia, Malta, Mexico, Monaco,
>   Nauru, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Oman, Palau, Papua New
>   Guinea, Philippines, Poland, Portugal, Republic of South Africa,
>   Republic of Marshall Islands, Samoa, San Marino, Singapore, Slovakia,
>   Slovenia, Solomon Islands, South Korea, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland,
>   Thailand, Tonga, Tuvalu, the United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom,
>   U.S.A., Vanuatu and Vatican City.

Also, [transit visas in Australia are free](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/transit/771/).